# I am unable to create fixed div relative to parent element

Tags: html, css

I want fixed buttons like amazon so that user can use them to scroll the products left and right, but my buttons moves along the products, here is my code:

```css
.scroll_btn_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.prod_scroll_btn {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.products_wrapper .scroll_btn_left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.products_wrapper .scroll_btn_right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.product_wrapper {
  height: inherit;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.product_wrapper .prod_zoom_btn {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product_wrapper .prod_zoom_btn img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="products_wrapper">
  <div class="scroll_btn_wrapper">

    <button class="scroll_btn_left prod_scroll_btn no_bd">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="scroll_btn_right prod_scroll_btn no_bd">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>

  </div>

  <% for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { %>
     <div class="product_wrapper">

         <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
            <img src="/images/products/phone1.jpg" alt="phone Image">
         </button>

     </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

NOTE: I am using ejs engine thats why for loop is valid...

Any resource to learn how to achieve this please help or answer if you got my point... As we see in most sites there are arrows on the left and right side of the main parent div, by clicking there use can scroll here and there but my buttons scroll along the div(product_wrapper), I can't use position fixed because that does not follows parent div (products_wrapper container) ,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, just few modification on the markup and some `CSS` (especially `overflow: auto` rule) will make your day !

So mainly we'll do :

- put the `button`s (left and right) directly under `.products_wrapper`.
- apply `position: relative` to `..products_wrapper` so the buttons can be positioned relatively to it.
- wrap all `div.product_wrapper` into a `div` that will have the overflowing elements (scroll) and at the same time allow the buttons to remain at their places.

Here's a demo containing the wanted result :

> For the demo purposes, I get rid of the loop and manually added some elements with `.product_wrapper` class (products).

```css
.products_wrapper {
  position: relative; /** to allow the button to position relatively to it **/
}

.prod_scroll_btn {
  position: absolute;
  /** next two lines center the buttons vertically **/
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.products_wrapper .scroll_btn_left {
  left: 0;
}

.products_wrapper .scroll_btn_right {
  right: 0;
}

/** the new wrapper for the products **/
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /** no line breaks **/
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto; /** allow horizontal scroll if needed **/
}

.cards .prod_zoom_btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cards .prod_zoom_btn img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- fontawesome -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" />

<!-- the "buttons" are now directly under ".products_wrapper" -->

<!-- the products (".product_wrapper") are wrapped into a "div" having "cards" as its class -->

<!-- I also used images from "https:placeholder.com" to have some basic images for the test -->

<div class="products_wrapper">
  <button class="scroll_btn_left prod_scroll_btn no_bd"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
  <button class="scroll_btn_right prod_scroll_btn no_bd"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="product_wrapper">
      <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="phone Image" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product_wrapper">
      <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="phone Image" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product_wrapper">
      <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="phone Image" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product_wrapper">
      <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="phone Image" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product_wrapper">
      <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="phone Image" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product_wrapper">
      <button class="prod_zoom_btn">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="phone Image" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.